# on how many elements Width="...." attribute is deprecated/non-valid in XHTML 1.0 strict?

Tags: xhtml, w3c

on how many elements `Width="...."` is attribute deprecated/non-valid in XHTML 1.0 strict? and where not?

After seen David's link i screenshoted the information of width

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/293985/110210134453-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/293985/110210134453-My-Desktop.png)

Comment: You're looking at this the wrong way, the question should be: *can I use `width` on element **x** that I want to use?*

Comment: I personally deprecate the attribute on *all* elements. I'm pretty important, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same as in HTML 4.01. You can count them on the [attributes table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html).

Comment: Probably. W3Schools is often wrong. Why do you mention that nasty little commercial organization though? I didn't mention them in my answer.

Comment: +1.  I chuckle to myself everytime someone mentions W3Schools, just because I've come to expect a comment from you expressing your hatred of them ;-)

Comment: according to this link width is allowed on Iframe, img, object, table, col and colgroup

Comment: XHTML what? There are several versions.

Comment: Hang on. "w3c schools"? There's no such entity. There is "the W3C" and there is "W3Schools". Two completely separate organizations, related only by the WWW.

Comment: XHTML 1.0 Strict .  and on this link "Border" is valid http://www.december.com/html/x1/element/td.html

Comment: XHTML 1.0 is HTML 4.01 in XML. There isn't any difference in the elements and attributes except those imposed by being XML (which basically means `xmlns` and mixed namespaces). And what does "border" have to do with anything? It hasn't been mentioned previously in this question.

Answer (score 1):

You've seen the official answer above, but I would urge you to think more about why you would use  `width` and `height` attributes in some instances and CSS in others.

With images, for example, usually every image on a page would be a different size. The size is also a property of the image itself and unrelated to the page layout. Therefore, you should normally use the width/height attributes on images.

The only exception is if you have a set of images all with the exact same dimensions (e.g. thumbnails in an image gallery). In this case, set a class on the wrapping element and target those images in CSS. The same approach may also apply to flash objects, if they're mad to fit a certain pixel size.

For pretty much every other element, use CSS instead of the attributes, because that would all be related to layout.